# Converting string to date in SQLServer, Arithmetic Overflow

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to convert a string "`PERIOD`" in this form `yyyymmdd` (eg: 20120701) into date in SQLServer.
So I used the convert function like this:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME,PERIOD,102);
```

and

```
 CONVERT(DATETIME,PERIOD,120);
```

but I'm getting an

> SqlException: "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to
>   data type datetime."
>
> This is the whole query, is there any other mistake in this?

```
"SELECT ACTUAL_N_WELLS, TARGET_N_WELLS, [YTD ACTUAL] AS YTD_ACTUAL, [YTD BUDGET] AS YTD_BUDGET FROM DASH_GL_DRILLING_PERF WHERE ASSET_NAME='Bu Hasa Asset' AND ( CONVERT(DATETIME,PERIOD,112) > (SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,-3,MAX(CONVERT(DATETIME,PERIOD,112))) from DASH_GL_DRILLING_PERF))");
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were a date format issue you would get an  out-of-range error, as your getting an overflow error check your not using an integer

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, 20120701, 102) - overflow
CONVERT(DATETIME,'20120701',102) - ok
```

Comment: thanks sir! that was indeed the issue, it was not vchar. The issue was solved when the data type was changed to vchar.

Answer (score 3):

Since it's yyyymmdd, you needed

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, PERIOD, 112)
```

Check out [CAST AND CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: sir, the problem is still persisting, I've edited the question to include the entire query.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

```
select Convert(date,CONVERT(DATETIME,'20120701',102));
```

This will convert the given period in date format.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @dt varchar(100)='20120701'
select convert(datetime,@dt)
```